# Recommended partition size of SD card for Ubuntu for BeagleBone black

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partition, sd-card

I am using 16GB SD card for building Ubuntu from scratch for BeagleBone Black.

So, I have to make two partition of my SD card, one for Rootfs and second one for Zimage and other stuff.

Initially I was providing 1GB for Rootfs and 15GB for Zimage, but Ubuntu was not working with this partition. So I provide 6GB for Rootfs and 10GB for Zimage.

Now Ubuntu is working fine, but I think 6GB is too much for Rootfs.

What should be the size of partition for Rootfs for best utilization of memory of SD card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have misunderstood something.  What `zimage` commonly refers to is the compiled linux kernel, so this sounds like a *boot* partition.  But that does not need to be very big at all.

[Looking at this](https://wiki.sabayon.org/index.php?title=Hitchhikers_Guide_to_the_BeagleBone_%28and_ARMv7a%29#Partitioning_a_MMC), it seems that the beaglebone (and I presume the BBB) uses a (small) VFAT partition to boot from.  This seems like a common ARM SOC methodology; it will contain a bootloader, some configuration files, and the kernel image -- although that page in fact recommends booting the kernel from the root filesystem, which would require a bootloader that supports FAT and ext.  I haven't used [uboot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Das_U-Boot#Supported_file_systems) but apparently it does.

In any case, if that's what you are referring to as the "Zimage" partition, 100 MB is easily *more than enough*.  [This example](http://www.adminempire.com/how-to-install-arch-linux-on-beaglebone-black-bbb/) uses 64 MB.  Not GB.  MB.  Chances are it will still be mostly empty, as even if the kernel `zimage` is stored there, that won't be anymore than ~5 MB, and it will be the biggest thing on the partition.  The kernel also makes use of loadable modules, but those are in the root filesystem, not the boot partition.

That leaves the rest of the card for the root filesystem.  There is no need to break that up and you might as well make it as big as possible, so I recommend you use the remaining 15.9 GB for it.  That's what's actually used by the system, whereas the boot partition is only used briefly at boot and doesn't even need to stay mounted.